# JavaFX Combox when something is selected property

Tags: javafx, combobox, properties

I have this large BooleanBinding.

```
BooleanBinding uncompleteBinding = txtBarcode.textProperty().isEmpty()
                            .or(txtNombre.textProperty().isEmpty()
                            .or(txtPrecioContado.textProperty().isEmpty())
                            .or(txtPrecioCredito.textProperty().isEmpty())
                            .or(txtModelo.textProperty().isEmpty()
                            .or(txtSerie.textProperty().isEmpty()

                            .or(cboCategoria.selectionModelProperty().isNull()
))));
```

The purpouse of the BooleanBinding is to enable a save button. It was working fine until i added Combobox into the mix. It doesn't seem to work that way. I tried isNotNull() and itemsProperty() as well.

By defaul't Combobox displays a "-" and nothing is selected. Is requiered that the user selects something, and there is no default selected value allowed.

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the value property to check the value chosen in the `ComboBox` and use `"-"` as prompt text.

Example:

```
ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();
cb.getItems().setAll("A", "B", "C");
cb.setPromptText("-");

Button btn = new Button("Submit");
btn.disableProperty().bind(cb.valueProperty().isNull());
```

Comment: Didn't knew about valueProperty. But in my scenario i need to use cboCategoria.valueProperty().isNotNull().not(). Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this idea:

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().isEqualTo(0);
```

where your "-" is located under 0 index.